# how to get only the file name without the File Path?

Tags: c#, winforms

i have this code:

```
openFileDialog1.Filter = "csv files (*.dbf)|*.dbf";
openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
openFileDialog1.FileName = "";

if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   dbf_File = openFileDialog1.FileName;
}
```

in dbf_File  i get all the file path and name (`c:\MyDir\MyFile.dbf`)

i need only the name - `MyFile.dbf`

Comment: Is there not any openFileDialog1.FileTitle?

Comment: @Rasel: No. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Only the file name (with extension):

```
dbf_File = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dbf_File);
```

Only the containing directory:

```
string dbf_Path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dbf_File);
```

Comment: thanks for the help !, and how to get only the path ? - (c:\MyDir) ?

Comment: You should check out other static methods under the **System.IO.Path** namespace. There are a bunch of useful stuff and they are pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 13):

[Path.GetFilenameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) -without extension

[Path.GetFilename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) - with extension

Answer (score 1):

I think you want [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx), which returns:

> The characters after the last directory character in path. If the last character of path is a directory or volume separator character, this method returns String.Empty.

(It sounds like contrary to your title, you *do* want the file extension - you don't want the path for the directory containing the file.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Path.GetFileName`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx

If you just wanted the file name without the extension as you said in the title (but then seemed not to want in your actual post), you can use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`.

Answer (score 1):

openFileDialog1.SafeFileName will get MyFile.dbf

Answer (score -1):

dbf_File  = path.split('\').getValue(path.split('\').Lenth-1);